# Can ETH miners check all the data which is stored in Ethereum?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

My doubt is from the below code:

```
contract RandomNumber{

    uint number;

    function get_random() public{
        bytes32 ramdonNumber = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp,blockhash(block.number-1)));
        number = uint(ramdonNumber);
    }
}
```

We assign a random number to the variable *number* but if I don't set *number* public or create another public function to retrieve the value then nobody would know the exactly value through Etherscan. But what about the miners? Can they retrieve these unrevealed data in some ways?

I have tried:
Google, Ethereum whitepaper, Solidity documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the contract is deployed on a public network (e.g. Ethereum), then the value is always readable.

Not directly through the autogenerated getter function (that's available only for `public` properties), which means it's not available onchain.

But anyone (including miners) can create an offchain app (for example in JavaScript) that queries the specific storage slot where the value is stored - in this case it's in slot number 0. And it returns the "secret" value.

JS code using `ethers` library, a wrapper to RPC API of Ethereum nodes:

```
const number = await provider.getStorageAt(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, SLOT_NUMBER);
```

Docs: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getStorageAt

And the actual RPC API method: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_getstorageat

Comment: Thank you! I have much understanding how data stores in slots with your reference attached below. But how about this:
    `function get_random() public view returns(uint num){
        bytes32 ramdonNumber = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp,blockhash(block.number-1)));
        num = uint(ramdonNumber);
        return num;
    }`
Is the variable num still stored in a certain slot?

Comment: In this case, the variable is only stored in memory - not in storage - and it won't be possible to retrieve it using the `getStorageAt` method... But - the block producer (miner on PoW, validator on PoS) knows the `block.number`, `block.timestamp` and `blockhash` parameters before publishing the block. And after the block has been published, the value is also retrievable by debugging the transaction. For example https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-debug#debugtracetransaction

Comment: So if I don't use `block.number`, `block.timestamp` as parameters in keccak256 hash function then miners/validators can't retrieve the value?

Comment: @Gap They can still retrieve the value before the transaction is included in the block. But they can also affect those `block.number` and other values mentioned in your snippet.